# Remove option item from dataset

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Am trying to achieve the following:

- The user can select a resource name from a datalist.
- The selected resource name will be created in another div.
- At the same time, the resource name should be removed from the original datalist. Just to prevent from having the user selecting the same resource name again.

I used the following HTML Code:

```
<div class="container-client">
<form action="#">
    <div class="user-details">
        <div class="input-box">
            <span class="details">Collaborateurs<small>*</small></span>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Selectionner un collaborateur" list="resource-list" required autocomplete="off" id="candidate">
                    <datalist id="customer-list">
                          <option value="Alex">Menuisier</option>
                          <option value="Peter">Charpentier</option>
                          <option value="Alain">Ingénieur béton</option>
                          <option value="Adam">Placo</option>
                    </datalist>
                </div>
                <div class="button-plus">
                    <input type="button" value="+" onClick="addResource();">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <hr>
        <form action="index.html">
            <div class="user-details">
                <div class="input-box">
                    <span class="details">Mon équipe:</span>
                </div>
                <div class="new-box" id="dynamic-list">
                                    
                </div>
                <div class="new-box">
                    <div class="button">
                        <input type="submit" value="✔">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Here below the JS code I tried to use; adding the resource name to the div works completely fine, however the removal of the resource name doesn't work.

```
function addResource()
{
    var new_team_member = document.getElementById ('dynamic-list');
    var generic_list = document.getElementById ('resource-list');
    var candidate = document.getElementById("candidate");
    if (candidate.value =='')
    {
        alert('No data selected');
    }
    else
    {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.setAttribute('class','input-box');
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.setAttribute('type','text');
        input.setAttribute('placeholder',candidate.value);
        input.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
        div.appendChild(input);
        new_team_member.appendChild(div);
        generic_list.removeChild(candidate);
        document.getElementById('candidate').value = '';
    }
}
```

The error message I got is about "*add-resources.js:20 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.*" indicating thatt the following JS line is causing the problem:  **generic_list.removeChild(candidate);**

Can you please help recommending a solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in the code, you provided the `resource-list` and `customer-list` look like they should be the same thing. In the input tag, the `customer-list` is used, and in the datalist, the `resource-list` is used. I've guessed that both of these should be `resource-list`, to link them correctly.

It looks like you are trying to get the datalist item that you clicked. In the code, as it is right now, you are removing the `<input>` tag as your `candidate` variable. If you would remove this, the whole input field would be gone, and the error is caused by this input field not being a child of the `generic_list` variable.

Now to solve this issue, you can use the `document.querySelector()` function to get the datalist item that was selected. The following change to your code would have the desired effect:

```js
function addResource()
{
    var new_team_member = document.getElementById ('dynamic-list');
    var generic_list = document.getElementById ('resource-list');
    var candidate = document.getElementById("candidate");
    if (candidate.value =='')
    {
        alert('No data selected');
    }
    else
    {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.setAttribute('class','input-box');
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.setAttribute('type','text');
        input.setAttribute('placeholder',candidate.value);
        input.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
        div.appendChild(input);
        new_team_member.appendChild(div);

        // Get datalist item with selected candidate
        datalist_item = document.querySelector('#resource-list option[value="'+CSS.escape(candidate.value)+'"]');
        // Remove item from list
        generic_list.removeChild(datalist_item);

        document.getElementById('candidate').value = '';
    }
}
```

This query selector allow you to use CSS like syntax to select elements. In the string `'#resource-list option[value="'+CSS.escape(candidate.value)+'"]'` it first finds the resource list, and then takes the option tag that has the candidate name as its value.
For security, I also use the `CSS.escape()` function that makes sure any name with special characters gets correctly escaped in this string.

Comment: Many thanks, now it works fine by following your recommendation.